# Python multidimensional array list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to make a program that will read a text file of names and numbers and make it into a 2d array with the names and numbers, then remove the item from the array if the number is 1. However, the code I wrote to access the index in the 2d array doesn't work and throws the error "IndexError: list index out of range". This is the block of code that isn't working:

```
for i in range(x):
    list2[i][1] = int(list2[i][1])
    if int(list2[i][1]) == 1:
        list2.pop(i)
```

This is the traceback:

```
File "/Users/cat/PycharmProjects/myCS106/Names.py", line 16, in updateNames
list2[i][1] = int(list2[i][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is an example of what list2 might look like:

```
[["John Doe","1"],["Jane Smith","0"],["Firstname Lastname","1"]]
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I correctly access the second part (in this case, the number) of the items in the array?

Comment: You are changing the length of the list while you iterate over it. It usually always invariably leads to problems. Is there some logical reason that you need to do that?

Comment: A list comprehension might be a clean way to remove the `1` values without `pop()`:
`list_without_ones = [element
                                 for element in list2
                                 if element[1] != 1]`. That is, create a copy of `list2` that filters out the unwanted values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you just want to remove some elements from the list you could iterate it from end to beginning which would allow you to remove items without causing `IndexError`:

```
list2 = [["John Doe","1"],["Jane Smith","0"],["Firstname Lastname","1"]]

for i in range(len(list2) - 1, -1, -1):
    list2[i][1] = int(list2[i][1])
    if int(list2[i][1]) == 1:
        list2.pop(i)

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[['Jane Smith', 0]]
```

Of course you could just use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list:

```
list2 = [[x[0], int(x[1])] for x in list2 if int(x[1]) != 1]
```